# Python giving an "IndentationError" for no apparent reason

Tags: python

I have this short code snippet, which doesn't work, and keeps on giving me this error:

[image: iMac-di-Luca:~ luca$ ./peasantlr.py | File "./peasantlr.py", line 24 | for char in data: | IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level]

I don't really find anything wrong in my code... I've checked, and there's no non-valid ASCII characters which may cause this error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def posts(data):

    postdata = ""

    for char in data:
        # If it's a non-escaped {, then it's the beginning of a post.
        if char == "{":
            insidepost = True
            # Skip to the char after {, start copying from there
            continue
        # If it's a non-escaped }, yield the post, and clean the buffer.
        if char == "}":
            insidepost = False
            yield postdata.replace("&lc;","{").replace("&rc;","}")
            postdata = ""
        # While in a post, copy the data into the post buffer.
        if insidepost:
            postdata += char

def findtags(data):
    tagdata = ""
    for char in data: *[This is the line which causes the error]*
        if char == "[":
            insidetag = True
            continue
        if char == "]":
            insidetag = False
            yield postdata
            postdata = ""
        if insidepost:
            postdata += char


f = """{A}{B}{c}{dDD}"""
for f in posts(f): print f
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you mixed tabs with spaces?

Comment: Try to run `python -tt peasantlr.py`.

Comment: Maybe the newline does not correspond to your OS?

Comment: @Bakuriu It still raises the same exception.

Comment: @Haidro I did... *facepalms* Those text editors try their best to kill my patience.

Comment: @Jetlef Heh, common problem :p. Glad to have helped!

Comment: @Jetlef: may I suggest turning on visible whitespace in future? It then becomes very easy to spot where you've mixed tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mixed tabs with spaces, which you shouldn't do. Per the [PEP 8 Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) spaces are used more than tabs, so try get into using spaces :D.

Comment: Great answer @Haidro although according to PEP 8 tabs only coding style is fine as long as spaces aren't introduced, I use a tab only style and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Check for the presence of tabs. E.g: in vim's normal mode, type: `/\t`

Comment: I already solved it, thanks. It was indeed a lone tabulation which broke the code.